# Java List values changes when any change in one of the element is made

Tags: java, list, collections

I am having a weird issue with java list. Please see the code below:

```
for ( int i=0; i < tripList.size(); i++ ) {
        ModeChoiceTrip trip = tripList.get(i);
        int newUniqueId = tripListIds[trip.uniqueId];
        int newLinkedId = trip.linkedId >= 0 ? tripListIds[trip.linkedId] : -1;
        int jointTripNum = trip.linkedId >= 0 && trip.tourType != TourTypes.SPECIAL_EVENT ? jointTripListIds[trip.linkedId] : 0;
        trip.uniqueId = newUniqueId;
        trip.linkedId = newLinkedId;
        trip.jointTripNum = jointTripNum;
    }
```

In the above code, the values in tripList seem correct but after executing a few iterations (up to i = 6), the values in tripList changes for all the positions.

I cannot provide the whole source code here but showing the snippet of the code where I have an issue.

I found that there are some duplicate trips in tripList. When one of the trips is changed, the copy of it (located at different position) is also changed.

Comment: Can we see how you did create the list (most likely how you put the same object N times in a list)

Comment: What should the values in trip list be at the start and the end?

Comment: List creation is a long code, which is a part of a very convoluted classes. I wont be able to paste it here.

Comment: The values in trip list has old ids for each trips. After the end of the loop, we assign them a new id (unique ids, linkedId, jointTripNum)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this piece of code is executed by multiple threads, Then there is every chance that List could be modified by another thread while this loop is going on.

you could try synchronizing the loop and see if issue gets resolved.

Also, you could try using for-each loop instead of the loop with counter.

```
for (ModeChoiceTrip trip : tripList) {
  .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried for-each loop and it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: @Gaurav -The for-each  loop on it's own won't solve it, you also need to try the synchronisation as suggested in the answer.

Comment: The issues was the duplicate values in the list. Thus, when I can a value in list the copy to that value changes as well.

Comment: @Gaurav consider adding your solution as an answer. it is ok to answer your own question if you manage to solve it, and shows that there is a solution for others that view this question.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was the duplicate values in the list. Thus, when I update a value in list the copy to that value changes as well

Answer (score 0):

You set the unique id to -1. So if the trip list id comes in as -1, you grab the index like  tripListIds[-1]; which might be the second to the last item in the list.